# flutter 2 MaterialApp buttonTheme for ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter, dart

in flutter 2 raised button deprecated in future

```
'RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use ElevatedButton instead.
```

but ThemeData in MaterialApp does not affect ElevatedButton

there is any solution for this?

this is my ThemeData

```
ThemeData(
      buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
          height: 40,
          buttonColor: Color(
              0xff00a89b
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(
                      50
                  )
              )
          )
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons) post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `elevatedButtonTheme` instead. [New buttons in flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons).

```dart
ThemeData(
  elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
    style: ButtonStyle(
      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<TextStyle>((states) {
        return ButtonTextTheme.primary;
      }), 
      foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) {
        return Color(0xff00a89b);
      }),
      shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<OutlinedBorder>((states) {
        return RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(50),
          ),
        );
      }),
    ),
  ),
);
```